# What is the appropriate way to store a Python string for the column qualifier in Google Bigtable?

Tags: google-cloud-bigtable

In Bigtable quickstart for "Perform a simple write" in Python (https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples/bigtable-quickstart#bigtable_quickstart-python), it shows for example:

```
row.set_cell(column_family_id, "connected_cell", 1, timestamp)
row.set_cell(column_family_id, "connected_wifi", 1, timestamp)
row.set_cell(column_family_id, "os_build", "PQ2A.190405.003", timestamp)
```

The string names for the column qualifiers are not stored using `bytes()` or specifying an encoding (i.e. `.encode("utf-8")`) etc.

In the Python reference (https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigtable/latest/row#setcellcolumnfamilyid-column-value-timestampnone), under "Parameters" we see that column is of type `bytes`.

Does the API handle storing the string as bytes? Or do I need to convert the column qualifier to bytes?

Comment: Based on this documentation on *class* [`ColumnFamily`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigtable/latest/column-family#class-googlecloudbigtablecolumnfamilycolumnfamilycolumnfamilyid-table-gcrulenone), **`column_family_id`** parameter is a string and values must be `[_a-zA-Z0-9][-_.a-zA-Z0-9]\*`. Does this address your question?

Comment: How do I give robert-g partial credit?

Comment: https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigtable/blob/c5116e097aacf9ddae249de57fab1849aff10d86/google/cloud/bigtable/row.py#L160 Shows it will convert a string to bytes. So Robert-g is correct.

Comment: I've posted my previous comment as an answer. Please check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my first comment, based on this documentation on *class* [`ColumnFamily`](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigtable/latest/column-family#class-googlecloudbigtablecolumnfamilycolumnfamilycolumnfamilyid-table-gcrulenone), `column_family_id` parameter is a string and values must be `[_a-zA-Z0-9][-_.a-zA-Z0-9]\*`.

Also, [@Adam C. Scott](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3661458/adam-c-scott) added that [`column = _to_bytes(column)`](https://github.com/googleapis/python-bigtable/blob/c5116e097aacf9ddae249de57fab1849aff10d86/google/cloud/bigtable/row.py#L160) this command will convert string to bytes.